# Task.WhenAll but process results one by one

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task, task-parallel-library

Let's say I have a list of Tasks, and I want to run them in parallel. But I don't need all of them to finish to continue, I can move on with just one. The following code waits for all the tasks to finish to move on. Is there a way for me to individually continue with the task that has completed while waiting for the other ones to finish?

```
List<string>[] x = await Task.WhenAll(new Task<List<string>>[] { task1, task2 })
// When task1 finishes, I want to process the result immediately
// instead of waiting on task2.
```

Comment: `ContinueWith`?

Comment: Use WhenAny? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany?view=netcore-3.1 See also https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/01/a-tour-of-task-part-7-continuations.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Task.WhenAny](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany?view=netcore-3.1) instead.

Example "stolen" from [Stephen Cleary's Blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/01/a-tour-of-task-part-7-continuations.html):

```
var client = new HttpClient();
string results = await await Task.WhenAny(
    client.GetStringAsync("http://example.com"),
    client.GetStringAsync("http://microsoft.com"));
// results contains the HTML for whichever website responded first.
```

### Responding to comment

You absolutely can keep track of the other tasks:

```
// supposing you have a list of Tasks in `myTasks`:
while (myTasks.Count > 0)
{
    var finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(myTasks);
    myTasks.Remove(finishedTask);
    handleFinishedTask(finishedTask); // assuming this is a method that
                                      // does the work on finished tasks.
}
```

The only thing you'd have to watch out for is:

> The returned task will always end in the `RanToCompletion` state with its Result set to the first task to complete. **This is true even if the first task to complete ended in the Canceled or Faulted state.**

[Remarks in `Task.WhenAny` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany#system-threading-tasks-task-whenany(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-threading-tasks-task)))) (emphasis by me).

Comment: Sounds good, but I still want the response from the ones that didn't finish first. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Absolutely. If you use just one `await` you'll get the Task that completed and can remove it from the list. Quite as in Richard's answer. In Stephen Cleary's Blog are many more examples. It's really worth a read, as is anything from that author.

Answer (score 6):

You're probably looking for [`Task.WhenAny`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany).

I've used it for setting off a pile of tasks and then processing each of them as they become ready, but I suppose you could also just wait for one to finish and continue without the loop if you don't care about dealing with the rest.

```
while (tasks.Count() > 0)
{
    var task = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
    tasks.Remove(task);
    var taskresult = await task;
    // process result
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using C# 8 and .NET Core you can take advantage of `IAsyncEnumerable` to hide this complexity from the consuming side.

Just like this:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await foreach (var data in GetData())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(data);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static async IAsyncEnumerable<string> GetData()
{
    List<Task<string>> tasks = new List<Task<string>> {GetData1(), GetData3(), GetData2()};

    while (tasks.Any())
    {
        var finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
        tasks.Remove(finishedTask);
        yield return await finishedTask;
    }
}

static async Task<string> GetData1()
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    return "Data1";
}

static async Task<string> GetData2()
{
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    return "Data2";
}

static async Task<string> GetData3()
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    return "Data3";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to process the results in order of the completion of the tasks, there is the [`OrderByCompletion`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/0361015459938f2eb8f3c1ad1021d19ee01c93a4/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/TaskExtensions.cs#L179-L260) extension method that does exactly that in Stephen Cleary's [Nito.AsyncEx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx) library, with the signature below:

```
// Creates a new collection of tasks that complete in order.
public static List<Task<T>> OrderByCompletion<T>(this IEnumerable<Task<T>> @this);
```

Usage example:

```
Task<string>[] tasks = new[] { task1, task2, task3, task4 };
foreach (var task in tasks.OrderByCompletion())
{
    string result = await task;
    // Do something with result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of Peter Csala, here a extension method for `IAsyncEnumerable`:

```
    public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> OrderedByCompletion<T>(this IEnumerable<Task<T>> tasks)
    {
        List<Task<T>> taskList = new List<Task<T>>(tasks);

        while (taskList.Count > 0)
        {
            var finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(taskList);
            taskList.Remove(finishedTask);
            yield return await finishedTask;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Be aware that the `await Task.WhenAny`-in-a-loop is an [inefficient antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72271006/ "Task.WhenAny - alternative to List avoiding O(N²) issues") with O(n²) complexity. It works, but it scales badly.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes. You can optimize this a lot, but as long as this isn't performance critical i would suggest to just stick with that. There are much fast ways to implement this, starting with using a dictionary and finishing with using a different implementation which doesn't run a loop.

Comment: Felix even if you switch from `List<T>` to `Dictionary<K,V>`, the complexity of this pattern is still O(n²).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes, as i said you can also implement this completely different, however it only worth the work if you really require that extra bit of performance.

Comment: Felix you don't have to do anything special. It's already implemented efficiently, at least three times. Just pick one of [Jon Skeet](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/01/16/eduasync-part-19-ordering-by-completion-ahead-of-time/)'s, [Stephen Toub](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/processing-tasks-as-they-complete/)'s or [Stephen Cleary](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/0361015459938f2eb8f3c1ad1021d19ee01c93a4/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/TaskExtensions.cs#L179-L260)'s implementation and you are done.

Comment: No, this is `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`, which isn't the same as `IEnumerable<T>`. Yes in the end it's almost the same results wise, still the way you write it and the way it can be used are different. I know Skeet's implementation and used it in the past.

Comment: Ah, so you didn't answer exactly what is asked in the question, but something closely related to this. A question where your answer would be a better fit is this: [How to implement an efficient WhenEach that streams an IAsyncEnumerable of task results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58194212/how-to-implement-an-efficient-wheneach-that-streams-an-iasyncenumerable-of-task)