# Map results tasks in a list, Tasks.ForEach

Tags: c#, async-await, task

The best I've been able to find in my research for a "do something with the results of tasks in a list as they complete" is this Microsoft page [Process asynchronous tasks as they complete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/start-multiple-async-tasks-and-process-them-as-they-complete?pivots=dotnet-6-0), unfortunately the example within accumulates the results of the tasks which I don't need to do; I only want to: spawn list of tasks, when a task completes, do something with its result.

So here I have adapted their example to demonstrate what I mean:

```cs
static async Task SumPageSizesAsync()
{
    IEnumerable<Task<int>> downloadTasksQuery =
        from url in s_urlList
        select ProcessUrlAsync(url, s_client);

    List<Task<int>> downloadTasks = downloadTasksQuery.ToList();
    while (downloadTasks.Any())
    {
        Task<int> finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(downloadTasks);
        downloadTasks.Remove(finishedTask);
        Console.WriteLine($"Just downloaded ${finishedTask} bytes");
    }
}
```

After any download task finishes, print an alert that it has finished (for example).

How can I more succinctly accomplish the same thing?

Is

```cs
downloadTasksQuery.Select(async t => Console.WriteLine($"Just downloaded ${await t} bytes"));
```

a good solution?

Comment: *"when a task completes, do something with its result."* -- It's not only a matter of succinctness. Your current code guarantees that the continuations will run sequentially, one at a time, but not necessarily in order of completion (there is a bias for the completed tasks towards the left side of the list). Are you OK with executing the continuations concurrently to each other (in parallel)?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias yes, concurrent continuations are OK. Is the MS example already the most succinct non-concurrent continuations version?

Comment: The more succinct non-concurrent way I know is to use the [`OrderByCompletion`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/0361015459938f2eb8f3c1ad1021d19ee01c93a4/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/TaskExtensions.cs#L184) extension method from Stepen Cleary's Nito.AsyncEx package. Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62678367/task-whenall-but-process-results-one-by-one/62684221#62684221). It is also more efficient than the `WhenAny`-in-a-loop approach, and without bias.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your approach is OK. Let's rewrite it in a less succinct way for clarity:

```
Task[] continuations = downloadTasksQuery
    .Select(async task =>
    {
        var result = await task;
        Console.WriteLine($"Just downloaded ${result} bytes")
    })
    .ToArray();

await Task.WhenAll(continuations);
```

The continuations will run on the current `SynchronizationContext`, if one exists, or on an unknown context otherwise. Without knowing the context, we can't say for sure if the continuations will be serialized or not.

Comment: Either way, `Console.WriteLine` is serialised.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman true. My understanding though is that the OP used the `Console.WriteLine` as an example.

Answer (score 1):

> research for a "do something with the results of tasks in a list as they complete" is this Microsoft page Process asynchronous tasks as they complete,

As I describe [in my book](https://stephencleary.com/book/) (section 2.6 "Processing Tasks as They Complete"), this is usually the wrong thing to search for.

Instead of thinking about the problem that way, compose the problem at a different level. Don't think about it as:

- Take a list of inputs
- Do asynchronous operation A on each input concurrently
- As each A completes, do operation B on the result of A

Instead, compose A and B together, and then you have:

- Take a list of inputs.
- Do asynchronous operation A+B on each input concurrently

The resulting code is much cleaner:

```
static async Task SumPageSizesAsync()
{
  // Composition is done with async+await
  var tasks = s_urlList.Select(async url =>
  {
    var result = await ProcessUrlAsync(url, s_client);
    Console.WriteLine($"Just downloaded {result} bytes");
  }).ToList();

  // Asynchronous concurrency is done with Select + Task.WhenAll
  await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```