# Concurrency with HttpClient doesn't seem to be working

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, httpclient, webclient

I know this is me missing something. I'm trying to make the move from `WebClient` to `HttpClient`. The code is accessing a 3rd party API that allows a certain number of 'threads' (concurrent requests) depending on user levels (between 1-7).

I read up on `HttpClient` and there's advice that you don't rely on it to manage concurrent downloads, so I implemented a queuing system using `SemaphoreSlim`. However, this resulted in 1 query per second no matter what I set the number of threads at.

I also implemented a straight `Parallel.ForEach` with the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` set to the user threads number. This also produced the above results.

I tried reverting to `WebClient` and I'm getting 5/second and this rate also reduces if I reduce the number of threads. Concurrent downloads is working in this instance.

The code (I comment out the 'Approach #' blocks to ensure only one is running for testing):

```cs
public HttpClient HttpClient { get; set; }

private static readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(7);
private int UserThreads = 7;

public async Task<List<ApiGetOutcome>> GetGameInfo(int systemID, List<string> romNames)
{
    // Code here defining vars: parameters, urlList
    // ApiGetOutcome just a class containing outcomes
    
    List<ApiGetOutcome> apiGetOutcomes = new List<ApiGetOutcome>();

    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = userThreads;
    ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri(ApiParameters.HostAddress)).ConnectionLimit = userThreads;

    Stopwatch SW = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    // APPROACH 1: Parallel.ForEach
    Parallel.ForEach(urlList, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = userThreads }, url =>
    {
        var getResult = HttpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
        string json = getResult.Result;
        apiGetOutcomes.Add(new ApiGetOutcome() { Data = json, Url = url });
        Debug.WriteLine("Rate: " + apiGetOutcomes.Count / SW.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
        Debug.WriteLine(apiGetOutcomes.Count);
    });
    // OUTCOME 1: steady stream of 1/s

    // APPROACH 2: Task/Semaphore mix
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (string url in urlList)
    {
        tasks.Add(PerformApiGet(url, HttpClient));
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    // OUTCOME 2: steady stream of 1/s

    // APPROACH 3: Parallel.ForEach using WebClient
    Parallel.ForEach(urlList, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = userThreads }, url =>
    {
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            var result = wc.DownloadString(new Uri(url));
            apiGetOutcomes.Add(new ApiGetOutcome() { Data = result, Url = url });
            Debug.WriteLine("Rate: " + apiGetOutcomes.Count / SW.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
            Debug.WriteLine(apiGetOutcomes.Count);
        }
    });
    // OUTCOME 3: steady stream of 5/s

    return apiGetOutcomes;
}

private static async Task PerformApiGet(string url, HttpClient httpClient)
{
    await semaphore.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        var getResult = httpClient.GetAsync(url);
        Debug.WriteLine("Downloaded: " + getResult.Result.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

I'm developing in .NET Framework 4.7. Any ideas?

Comment: Check out this: [What is HttpClient's default maximum connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735569/what-is-httpclients-default-maximum-connections). Are all URLs in the `urlList` in the same domain?

Comment: As a side-note the `List<T>` is not thread-safe, so the unsynchronized `apiGetOutcomes.Add` inside the parallel `body` delegate is erroneous usage of the API.

Comment: `var getResult = httpClient.GetAsync(url);` should be `var getResult = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);` you are blocking the whole thread by calling `.Result` erroneously on the next line.

Comment: Since (as @Charlieface pointing out) you are locking thread with a semaphore for whole duration of the request (with using `.Result` before/without `await` ) behavior you describe is expected. It is unclear if this is due to misunderstanding of how async works (unlikely that there are examples of correct usage in the sample) or just typo. Voted to close as typo - consider to [edit] to clarify if you need some explanations.

Comment: @Charlieface the OP is targeting the .NET Framework, so they don't have access to the [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync), and the `Parallel.ForEach` cannot be used with `async`/`await`. Using the `.Result` isn't ideal, but it shouldn't have the effect that the OP is observing (killing the parallelization). Most likely something else is going on. The `HttpClient.GetStringAsync().Result` is not much different than the `WebClient.DownloadString`. Both are blocking the current thread.

Comment: To exclude the possibility that the observed behavior is caused by `ThreadPool` saturation, you could try adding this line at the start of the program: `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);`, and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias have you looked at the code carefully? OP makes sure there are no requests with HttpClient running in parallel by using semaphore around whole call. (Which is the difference from their WebClient code that allowed to run in parallel... It is hard to expect that type of synchronization - so it is very easy to miss)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov the semaphore is initialized with `new SemaphoreSlim(7)`, so it has capacity for 7 concurrent actions. The OP is using it as a throttler, not as a mutex.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias you are right about semaphore, but it looks like it does not matter... I totally missed the fact that at least `for` version runs completely synchronously, so not interesting at all. The `Parallel.ForEach` is likely also run sequentially if OP testing in WinForm/WPF app... Need more details... (In real code OP likely don't do such a crazy not-really-compatible mix of threading/async concepts, so hopefully code is for pure educational purpose to hone code review skills - which I failed clearly)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I too missed that inside the `async` method `PerformApiGet` (approach 2) the `getResult.Result` is used instead of `await getResult`, so this method will always complete synchronously. So inside the `foreach` loop the `tasks.Add(` adds one completed task after the other. Alas it's not surprising that all the work is serialized. The behavior of the `Parallel.ForEach` (approach 1) is still puzzling to me though.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Not sure you're right. In version 2, the call to `PerformApiGet` will block the UI thread (assuming UI synchronization context) because of the `.Result`, so the function will not return immediately unless the semaphore blocked.

Comment: @Charlieface yes, in the approach 2 the `PerformApiGet` will complete synchronously, whatever the synchronization context is. The semaphore won't throttle anything because there is no concurrency. Each invocation has to complete before the next can start.

Comment: @Theodore (+ Alexia, Charlieface) - thanks for all the answers. I'm an amateur/self-taught coder, so please be gentle! You're right in terms of my grip on async coding is a little shaky. I guess the short question to you would be, how would you achieve this in code? That is: how to perform a specified number of concurrent downloads using HttpClient? I put the full code here (contains some superfluous code): https://pastebin.com/embed_js/MU3E9PZV"

Answer (score 0):

`PerformApiGet` is blocking on `.Result`, which is going to cause concurrency issues if you are in a synchronization context (such as WinForms or WPF).

`GetAsync` also returns a `HttpResponseMessage`, which needs disposing with `using`. But you probably intended for `GetStringAsync` anyway.

```cs
private static async Task PerformApiGet(string url, HttpClient httpClient)
{
    await semaphore.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
        Debug.WriteLine("Downloaded: " + response);
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

---

A more common way of throttling tasks is to just check the size of the list, and wait for one to complete before adding more.

```cs
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (string url in urlList)
{
    if (tasks.Count >= UserThreads)
    {
        var finished = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
        tasks.Remove(finished);
    }

    tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => {
        var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
        Debug.WriteLine("Downloaded: " + response);
    }));
}
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: I am not sure that using the `Task.WhenAny` is more common than using a `SemaphoreSlim` for throttling tasks. The `Task.WhenAny` is an [antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43763982/how-to-use-task-whenany-and-implement-retry/43764680#43764680). It wastefully attaches and detaches continuations on all active tasks in every iteration. Its complexity is [O(n*k)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72271006/task-whenany-alternative-to-list-avoiding-on%c2%b2-issues), compared to `SemaphoreSlim`'s O(n).

Comment: Thanks for the code, @Charlieface. Regarding your first code block, this still runs @ 1 result/s, so I suspect it is still running concurrently. Your second block of code didn't compile (#CS1660) but I did try replacing the lambda with ` tasks.Add(PerformApiGet(url, HttpClient));` No dice - still 1/second. No closer to a solution :(

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Whether it's more common or not is hard to say (probably needs some GitHub analysis or something). But it's certainly simpler. As to the O(nk) problem: it's simply not a factor when you are doing long web requests, and when the size of your list is tiny and the number of overall tasks isn't that big either. It's just not something you should really think about. Yes if you are running a webserver or doing thousands or millions of reqs/sec then you should rethink this, but I doubt `SempahoreSlim` would be the answer then either.

Comment: @stigzler Should be fixed now.

Comment: Charlieface I agree that in most usage scenarios the O(n*k) complexity of the `Task.WhenAny` won't emerge as a performance problem. Nevertheless I don't think that in this application it is simpler than the `SemaphoreSlim`. You could rename the `_semaphore` field to `_throttler`, and make obvious to anyone what is the purpose of this field. The `Task.WhenAny` is not obvious, and without adding comments anyone who reads this code for the first time will be puzzled.